# Como usar o CMake para compilar um projeto com múltiplas bibliotecas

Tags: c++, cmake

Estou tentando desenvolver um jogo em `OpenGL`, mas a IDE que eu utilizo faz uso do `CMake` e eu não estou conseguindo configurar o projeto. Estou totalmente perdido. Procurei diversos tutoriais de CMake na internet, mas eles são muito confusos e parece que cada um faz de um jeito diferente. Preciso de ajuda para configurar o CMake da maneira mais correta o possível.
Essa é a estrutura do meu projeto (segui a ideia [desse](https://medium.com/heuristics/c-application-development-part-1-project-structure-454b00f9eddc) artigo)

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── libs
│   ├── GLEW
│   │   ├── include
│   │   │   └── GL
│   │   │       ├── eglew.h
│   │   │       ├── glew.h
│   │   │       ├── glxew.h
│   │   │       └── wglew.h
│   │   └── lib
│   │       └── libGLEW.a
│   ├── GLFW
│   │   ├── include
│   │   │   └── GLFW
│   │   │       ├── glfw3.h
│   │   │       └── glfw3native.h
│   │   └── lib
│   │       └── libglfw3.a
│   └── Logging
│       ├── include
│       │   └── Logging
│       │       └── Logger.hpp
│       └── src
│           └── Logger.cpp
└── src
    └── main.cpp
```

Esse é o `main.cpp`

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <Logging/Logger.hpp>

int main(void)
{
    Logger logger;
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        logger.error("Failed to create a window");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Por favor, me indiquem um tutorial bem estruturado de CMake. Eu preciso aprender a utulizá-lo de forma correta.

Answer (score 1):

Para a estrutura que você mostrou uma solução poderia ter 2 arquivos CMakeList.txt:

```
1. CMakeLists.txt (na raíz do projeto)
2. src/CMakeLists.txt
```

O primeiro CMakeLists.txt (na raiz do projeto) poderá ser mais ou menos assim:

```
project (test_gl)

# includes do OpenGL
set (GLEW_INC_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/GLEW/include/GL)
set (GLFW_INC_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/GLFW)

# libs do OpenGL
set (GLEW_LIB_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/GLEW/lib)
set (GLFW_LIB_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/GLFW/lib)

# includes de log
set (LOG_INC_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/Logging/include)

# fontes de log
set (LOG_SRC_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/Logging/src)

# diretorio dos fontes da aplicacao
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
```

O segundo CMakeLists.txt (no diretório src) poderá ser mais ou menos assim:

```
include_directories(${GLEW_INC_DIR} ${GLFW_INC_DIR} ${LOG_INC_DIR})
link_directories(${GLEW_LIB_DIR} ${GLFW_LIB_DIR})
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
add_executable(hello_gl main.cpp ${LOG_SRC_DIR)/Logger.cpp}
target_link_directories(hello_gl libGLEW.a libglfw3.a)
```

O programa executável criado pelo build terá o nome "hello_gl", e será criado no diretório "src".

Para gerar os arquivos de build você cai precisar rodar os comandos

```
make _BUILD_DIR
cd _BUILD_DIR
cmake -G generator ..
```

Os dois primeiros comandos não são realmente necessários, mas eles produzem um build "out-of-tree", isto é, o build não vai poluir o seu diretório de projetos (todos os arquivos criados pelo cmake vão ficar embaixo do subdiretório _BUILD_DIR (usei o nome _BUILD_DIR, mas pode ser qualquer nome)

O "generator" no comando cmake vai dizer para qual IDE ou sistema de build o cmake vai gerar os arquivos. [Esta página](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) no site do cmake mostra os sistemas de build suportados. Por exemplo, para gerar uma solução para o Visual Studio 2013 o comando acima seria

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013" ..
```

É mais ou menos isso.